# Resource allocation problem with mystic yields suboptimal solution

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, mystic

Consider the notation and objective below for this sequential resource allocation problem:

Spend/Cost timestep i channel j: C_{i, j}

Total resource: B

Horizon: H

Max allocation jump between time-steps: 1 / 0.4

Minimum allocation : min_total_spend_channel_i

target ROI: targetvalue

planned spend over horizon: P = (C_{1, 1}, C_{1, 2}.....C_{H, 1}, C_{H, 2})

We have a time-variant predictor for the amount of sales on a specific day. For a certain timestep it takes the following form:

sales_{i, j} = coeff_{i, j} * spend_{i, j}^{saturation_{{i, j}}}

where as i denotes the timestep and j denotes the channel.

The following holds: 0 <= saturation_{i ,j} <= 1 , notice that this curve exhibits diminishing marginal returns and is concave when minimizing thus convex when maximizing.

The total sales over the horizon can then be expressed as:

totalsales(P) = \sum_{i}\sum_{j} coeff_{i, j} * spend_{i, j}^{saturation_{{i, j}}}

The aim of this optimization task is to maximize the spend whilst maintaining a target ROI(return on investment). We also have some constraints we want our solution to adhere to such as minimum spend per channel, total budget constraint, max jump between the budgeting between one day and another.

We construct the following optimization problem:

[image]

This is a toy example and not the real life example i am working on.

However, before touching on that i want to get this working.
Since my real problem is more complex and especially the sales-predictor i been trying to find a python optimizer that can solve constrained nonlinear nonconvex optimization problems.

After browsing through this forum i stumbled upon mystic and gave it a go:

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from typing import List
import mystic
import pandas as pd
from mystic.symbolic import simplify
from mystic.symbolic import generate_constraint, generate_solvers
from mystic.monitors import VerboseMonitor
from mystic.penalty import quadratic_inequality
from mystic.penalty import linear_inequality

def adstock_geometric(x: List, theta: float):
    x_decayed = np.zeros_like(x)
    x_decayed[0] = x[0]

    for xi in range(1, len(x_decayed)):
        x_decayed[xi] = x[xi] + theta * x_decayed[xi - 1]

    return x_decayed


def getobjective2_(x):

    adstocks = {'adstock-channel_1': np.array(0.08223851),
                'adstock-channel_2': np.array(0.28487006)}
    channels = ['channel_1', 'channel_2']
    horizon = 12
    coeffs = pd.DataFrame({'channel_2-saturationcoefficients': [0.73651 for _ in range(horizon)],
                           'timevar-channel_2': [0.27527, 0.14287, 0.12847, 0.02112,
                                                 0.03544, 0.05230, 0.21811, 0.27527,
                                                 0.14287, 0.12847, 0.02112, 0.03544],
                           'channel_1-saturationcoefficients': [0.70259 for _ in range(horizon)],
                           'timevar-channel_1': [0.13827, 0.24760, 0.28849,
                                                 0.33613, 0.34027, 0.28988,
                                                 0.21095, 0.13827, 0.24760,
                                                 0.28849, 0.33613, 0.34027]})

    incomingcostchannel_1 = np.array([0.10303531, 0.07283391, 0.14465764, 0.12315725, 0.07384496, 0.07709148,
                                      0.06425854, 0.09207129, 0.04114219, 0.04066119, 0.09510273, 0.06785441,
                                      0.08381945, 0.05025105, 0.0617348,  0.08135422, 0.04006317, 0.0348892,
                                      0.05374626, 0.05904413])
    incomingcoostchannel_2 = np.array([0.04199663, 0.05350016, 0.05427114, 0.05519786, 0.05449486, 0.05733955,
                                      0.0572036,  0.05479,    0.06165305, 0.06347637, 0.05837555, 0.05841943,
                                      0.05922741, 0.05826971, 0.05652555, 0.06605174, 0.0603985,  0.0617391,
                                      0.05811569, 0.05972648])

    def saturate(cost, channel):
        return np.power(cost, coeffs[f'{channel}-saturationcoefficients'].values)


    tbret = 0

    for idx, channel in enumerate(channels):
        try:
            adstockchannel = adstocks[f'adstock-{channel}']
        except KeyError:
            adstockchannel = 0.0

        costchannel = x[(idx * horizon): (idx * horizon) + horizon]

        if channel == "channel_1":
            incomingcost = incomingcostchannel_1
        else:
            incomingcost = incomingcoostchannel_2

        zerosoverhorizon = np.zeros(horizon)
        incomingcostoverhorizon = np.append(incomingcost, zerosoverhorizon)
        incomingcostoverhorizonadstocked = adstock_geometric(x=incomingcostoverhorizon,
                                                             theta=adstockchannel)[-horizon:]

        costchannel += incomingcostoverhorizonadstocked
        costadstocked = adstock_geometric(x=costchannel,
                                          theta=adstockchannel)
        costmediaprocessed = saturate(cost=costadstocked, channel=channel)

        costready = costmediaprocessed * coeffs[f'timevar-{channel}']

        tbret += sum(costready)
    return -tbret

def generatemysticconstraints(horizon, totalbudget, channels, minspendtotalconstraints,
                              maxjumps, maxcovers):
    xs = [f"x{idx}" for idx in range(horizon * len(channels))]

    constraints = ""
    totalbudgetconstraint = f"{totalbudget} >= {'+'.join(xs)}"
    constraints += totalbudgetconstraint

    breakpoints = {channel: idx * horizon for idx, channel in enumerate(channels)}
    for channel, cutoff in breakpoints.items():
        fromx = cutoff
        tox = cutoff + horizon

        minspendchannel = minspendtotalconstraints[channel]

        maxjump = maxjumps[channel]
        maxcover = maxcovers[channel]

        minspendconstrainttotal = f"{'+'.join(xs[fromx: tox])} >= {minspendchannel}"
        constraints += '\n'
        constraints += minspendconstrainttotal

        for idx in range(fromx + 1, tox):
            maxjumpconstraint_ = f"({xs[idx - 1]} * {maxjump}) >= {xs[idx]}"
            constraints += '\n'
            constraints += maxjumpconstraint_

        for idx in range(fromx, tox - 1):
            maxcoverconstraint_ = f"({xs[idx + 1]} * {maxcover}) >= {xs[idx]}"
            constraints += '\n'
            constraints += maxcoverconstraint_
    return constraints

def run():
    scalefactor = 11621.64675797
    scalefactorresponse = 118257.501641172

    totalbudget = 150_000 / scalefactor

    horizon = 12

    minspendtotalconstraints = {'channel_2': 0.0,
                                'channel_1': 0.0}

    targetvalue = 4.0

    channels = ['channel_1', 'channel_2']

    objective = getobjective2_

    strategy = "targetroas"

    maxjumps = {'channel_1': 2.5,
                'channel_2': 1.5}
    maxcovers = {'channel_1': 2.5,
                 'channel_2': 1.5}

    x0 = [0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407,
          0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407,
          0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407,
          0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407,
          0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407,
          0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407]

    boundsextrapolation = [(0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933), (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933), (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933), (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933), (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933), (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933), (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604), (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604), (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604), (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604), (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604), (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604)]

    constraints = generatemysticconstraints(horizon=horizon,
                                            totalbudget=totalbudget,
                                            channels=channels,
                                            minspendtotalconstraints=minspendtotalconstraints,
                                            maxjumps=maxjumps,
                                            maxcovers=maxcovers)
    def targetpenalty(x, target):
        if strategy == "targetroas":
            return target * (sum(x) * scalefactor) - (-objective(x) * scalefactorresponse)
        elif strategy == "targetcpa":
            return (sum(x) * scalefactor) - target * (-objective(x) * scalefactorresponse)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError

    @linear_inequality(condition=targetpenalty, kwds={'target': targetvalue})
    def penalty(x):
        return 0.0

    constraintsimplified = simplify(constraints,
                                    all=True)

    from mystic.constraints import and_

    generatedconstraints = generate_constraint(generate_solvers(constraintsimplified), join=and_)

    stepmon = VerboseMonitor(1)

    cost = lambda x: -sum(x)

    bounds = boundsextrapolation

    optimum = mystic.solvers.diffev2(cost,
                                     x0=x0,
                                     constraints=generatedconstraints,
                                     bounds=bounds,
                                     penalty=penalty,
                                     full_output=True,
                                     stepmon=stepmon,
                                     disp=True,
                                     tightrange=True,
                                     npop=400,
                                     gtol=200,
                                     maxiter=10000)

    optimalvalueslst = optimum[0]

    totalspent = np.sum(optimalvalueslst) * scalefactor

    sales = -objective(optimalvalueslst) * scalefactorresponse

    estimatedcpa = totalspent / sales
    estimatedroas = sales / totalspent

    penaltyvalue = targetvalue * sum(optimalvalueslst) - (-objective(optimalvalueslst))

    print(f"total spent: {totalspent}")
    print(f"estimated cpa: {estimatedcpa}")
    print(f"estimated roas: {estimatedroas}")
    print(f"penalty value: {penaltyvalue}")

    return {'x': optimalvalueslst}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vals = run()

    print(vals)
```

The result is far from optimal, the penalty gets heavily violated. I browsed through the docs but couldnt find an obvious explanation.

Note that an solution exists and that the resulting penaltyvalue printed should be close to zero and the whole budget B spent. Which is not the case, removing the penalty makes it possible to at least spend the budget up to an arbitrary constant, but as soon as the penalty gets into play we get very very far of from the solution.

Answer (score 0):

After multiplying both sides of (6) by the denominator, the problem looks linear to me. A linear solver would be more appropriate.

Caveat: I don't know what `totalSales(P)` is. I think it may be exogenous (as it depends only on `P` which is exogenous), but that is a guess.

Comment: the formulation of totalSales(P) is written in the problem description, maybe it would have been more clear to include it in the actual picture of the formal definition of the problem:  totalsales(P) = \sum_{i}\sum_{j} coeff_{i, j} * spend_{i, j}^{saturation_{{i, j}}}

Comment: Notation is very iffy. First, I would clean up the math. (E.g. `totalSales(P)` means normally that totalSales depends only on `P`, there is `C[i,j]` and `Spend[i,j]`). Too much reverse engineering is needed to understand this. Having said that, there are quite a few global NLP solvers available (not SciPy which mostly has inferior algorithms).